Group Representation and Particle
In quantum mechanics, a particle is an irreducible unitary Poincaré group representation on a Hilbert space $H$. This is because a particle exists objectively which does not depend on observers.
I have a question for this. In this point of view, please correct me if I misunderstand it, action of the Poincaré group looks like a passive transform which is only an observer effect. But a ray in the abstract Hilbert space $H$ means a state of a particle. Shouldn’t the notion of ‘state’ be something coordinate-free before we represented it in a reference frame? If a state in $H$ is independent with any observer, why do we act it by Poincaré group which is a passive transform depending on observers?
I understand that wave functions depend on reference frame. But before we represent state as a wave function in a reference frame, shouldn’t it be an absolute notion? For example, for different observers, my understanding is that a given particle refers to the same ray in $H$ though it may have different wave functions for these observers.

Edit: I'm reading the following Wikipedia page:

...the different quantum states of an elementary particle give rise to an irreducible representation of the Poincaré group.


In quantum mechanics, any particular one-particle state is represented as a vector in a Hilbert space
$H$. To help understand what types of particles can exist, it is important to classify the possibilities for
$H$
allowed by symmetries, and their properties. Let
$H$
be a Hilbert space describing a particular quantum system and let
$G$ be a group of symmetries of the quantum system.

If I understand these paragraphs correctly, a representation on $H$ represent all quantum states of 'a' particle.
My question is: an element $v\in H$ seems to be a abstract quantum state which is observer-free. In this case, why do we act Poincare group on it as passive transforms? I think passive transforms should be some kind of coordinate change for different observers.

The role of the Poincare group is not to pick out any one observer; it is to pick out those properties that look the same to all observers --- that is, the observer-independent properties of the particle itself.

Does an element $v\in H$ depend on the observer? I know the corresponding wave function $\psi$, which represents $v$ under a chosen basis, depends on the observer. But does $v$, as an abstract state of the system, depend on the observer too?

@Hydrogen:  1)  The state of the system is what it is, independent of the observer.  2)  It is possible that you don't know the state of the system, in which case your knowledge is represented by a probability distribution over the state space.  Different observers might have different probability distributions, because different observers might have different information.  3)  Those probability distributions are sometimes called "mixed states", which can be confusing because in general a mixed state is NOT a state (in the sense of being an element of the state space).

@Hydrogen:  4)  Even more confusingly, sometimes people say "state" when they mean "mixed state".  5)  But the bottom line is that the state of a quantum system, represented by a wave function, is characteristic of the system itself and is observer-independent.

@Hydrogen:  PS:  "I know the corresponding wave function ψ
, which represents v
under a chosen basis, depends on the observer. "   This is not correct.  A  state is an equivalence class of wave functions.

I may misunderstand the meaning of state. Does a state mean an element $v\in H$? If not, what does a particular $v\in H$ stand for?

@Hydrogen:  $H$ is the space of wave functions (or, depending on context, some abstract Hilbert space).  A state is a line through the origin  in $H$.  We often abuse language and use the same symbol $v$ for both  an element of $H$ and the (unique) state it belongs to.

If $v\in H$, or say the ray $\mathbb C\cdot v\subseteq H$, stands for a state, why does Poincare group act on $v$? Shouldn't this action be trivial because $v$ is independent of the observer?

@Hydrogen:  I describe the universe in terms of coordinates $x$ and $t$.  You describe it in terms of coordinates $x'$ and $t'$.  A state $v$ is represented by a function that I call $\phi(x,t)$ and you call $\psi(x',t')$.  These are different notations for the same function.   Here's what this means:  Suppose for simplicity that $x'=Ax+Bt$ and $t'=Cx+Dt$.  (In other words, $\phi(x,t)=\psi(Ax+Bt,Cx+Dt)$, on the nose.)   (CONTINUED)

(CONTINUED).   Now there is an element of the Poincare group that takes $v=\phi(x,t)=\psi(x',t')$ to $v'=\phi(x',t')$, which is not the same as $v$.  The states $v$ and $v'$ are what they are, independent of who's observing them.  But $v'$ is related to $v$ by comparing the way the world looks to different observers.  The point is that if you look through the eyes of a different observer, none of the laws of physics should change.  So, for example, if the state $v$ evolves into the state $w$, then the state $v'$ evolves into the state $w'$.

@Hydrogen:  And finally, the whole point.   Suppose you have an element of the Poincare group that maps $v$ to $v'$ and $w$ to $w'$.  Suppose you have a proposed law of physics that says the state $v$ eventually evolves into the state $w$, but that $v'$ does NOT eventually evolve into the state $w'$.   That essentially says that the laws of physics look very different to me than they do to you.   We assume this is impossible, so you can RULE OUT your proposed law of physics.     The Poincare group is a tool for ruling out many possibilities for physical laws.

I believe the problem is essentially about the ideas of covariance.
A vector in space is probably is a very well-familiar object for you. The vector exist independently of any coordinate system, but different "observers" have different numerical representations of this object due to the difference in the sets of bases they use.
The idea of covariance is that to every symmetry transformation (which we might associate with changes to the point of view of different observers) can be associated with a rule to transform the numerical representation of the same object.
To summarize, there is an invariant object (vector) and covariant object (components of the vector in a particular frame).
It is important to note that there is a degree of arbitrariness in choosing which mathematical objects are invariant and which are covariant. The only logical requirement is that "physically observable quantities", such as lengths or angles, are independent of which observer calculates them.
My main point is that in QM this arbitrary choice is made differently. The same physical setup (e.g. a particle with its spin along the line from the Earth to the Sun) is represented by different mathematical object (vector in Hilbert space) for every other observer. There is, however, no contradiction, since every physical quantity depends on the inner product of bra and ket states, which together change to no net effect, the same way that basis vectors of different observers and coordinates of a vector.
In principle, it should be logically possible to view symmetry transformations in QM keeping physical states constant. That would require the "measuring sticks" of different observers to be different states in the Hilbert space.
The conventional choice is made so that for every observer an "up" spin state means a particle that would go only "up" in a Stern-Gerlach experiment in their reference frame. Since different observers might have their SG apparatus rotated differently, the "up" state in Hilbert state represents a different physical reality depending on the observer.

Do you mean 'invariant vs covariant' is like 'vector vs components under some frame' in line algebra? I think an element in Hilbert space should be a 'vector'. Do you mean even for vectors, they are different for different observers?

Exactly, by 'invariant vs covariant' I mean the difference between the vector and its components in linear algebra. In quantum mechanics the roles are kind of reversed: your measurement outcomes are kind of like components of a vector, while the state in the Hilbert space is the vector itself. After all, since Hilbert spaces are abstract, the relation between the elements of the Hilbert spaces of two observers has a certain freedom. We pinpoint this relation by invariance of measurement outcomes and covariance of measuring bra states. Once again, think about "up" state for different observers.

The crucial point is that measurement outcomes are the thing that has to be invariant, i.e. "invariant components => changing vector" in linear algebra terms.

Wait, do you mean for the same particle in the same state, its vector in $H$ can be different for different observers?

Yes. A spin in the up state would be in a down state for a observer rotated by 180 degrees.
